# How to identify utterance of a word in a sound signal

Tags: python, python-3.x, signal-processing

I have a .WAV file (little-endian, 16 bit, mono, 16000hz PCM format) which contains a utterances of words with approximately 2 seconds of silence in between each word. Each utterance is approximately 3/4th of a second long (on average). I want a way to segregate each utterance in a separate file. The individual files should be in the same format, starting with 1-2 seconds of silence, followed by the utterance, and ending immediately after the utterance is over.The way I did it was have a manual threshold value for signal strength and whenever the signal strength crosses the threshold, I cut out a two second window. However, if the length of utterance varies, or there is a false activation, the manual threshold method is useless.

Is there a way to dynamically detect the onset of a word without specifying a manual threshold or a fixed window size to cut? How can I approximately detect when the word begins and ends? I wrote the following code

```
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np

def main():
    '''
    Driver Function
    '''
    sample_rate, data = wavfile.read('filename.wav')
    threshold = 2000
    file_count = 0

    i = 0
    while(i < data.shape[0]):
        if(abs(data[i]) > threshold):
            i = record(i, data, file_count, sample_rate)
            file_count += 1

        else:
            i += 1


def record(index, data, file_count, sample_rate):
    '''
    Records approximately 2 seconds of .wav file by cutting at the given index
    Returns the index where recording ended
    '''

    start_index = index - sample_rate # start 1 second before word detected
    end_index = index + sample_rate # end 1 second after it is detected

    file_name = "newfile--" + str(file_count) + ".wav"
    wavfile.write(file_name, sample_rate, data[start_index:end_index])

    return end_index

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: The basic class of algorithms you might be looking for are call "voice activity detection" methods.  Lots of them depending your computational load and error rate requirements.  etc.

Comment: Thanks for that @hotpaw2 Could you recommend me the best method for a 5 minute long audio clip with approximately 75 utterances? I would like the error rate as low as possible.